# How to select features by distance in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I have a marker layer as GeoJSON and want to select from this group those that fall within x miles of any user selected location. So the map just shows selected locations.

Are there examples or plugins for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of any plugins available, but you should be able to write your own code to use the [latLng.distanceTo](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng-distanceto) method.

Something like this pseudocode:

```
foreach(item in geoJsonResult){
    // distanceTo returns meters
    if(L.latLng(item.latLng).distanceTo(userLocation) < 100000) 
        toMap.add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks exactly like what [Turf.js](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/coffee-with-turf/) is designed for.